# match the string in a file and print the next column

Tags: awk, grep

I have two files input1.txt and input2.txt.

input1.txt has following details:

```
abcd.net
bcad.net
cagh.net
degh.net
usna.net
```

input2.txt has following details:

```
abcd.net 169.254.0.2
bcad.net 169.254.0.3
cagh.net 169.254.0.4
us-1212-qwe.net 169.254.232.50
us-cisco.net 10.120.2.3
degh.net 169.254.0.5
usna.net 169.254.0.6
ab1234.net 169.254.0.7
catorr.net 169.254.0.8
```

I need to get the corresponding IP details of the servers listed in "input1.txt" from the file "input2.txt"

Output should be like this:

```
abcd.net 169.254.0.2
bcad.net 169.254.0.3
cagh.net 169.254.0.4
degh.net 169.254.0.5
usna.net 169.254.0.6
```

My code as shown below is not working properly. Please help.

```
  for i in `cat input1.txt`; do more input2.txt | grep -w "^$i"; done
```

Comment: Every time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ip[$1]=$2} FNR!= NR {print $1, ip[$1]}' input2.txt input1.txt
```

This reads through input2.txt and builds an array of the desired data, indexed by the first column.  Then it reads intput1.txt and for each line prints the host plus the data in the array.

Note, the answer given above no longer applies, as the question has been edited.  For the edited question, you can do:

```
 awk 'FNR==NR{ip[$1".net"]=$2} FNR!= NR {print $1, ip[$1]}' input2.txt input1.txt
```

but this is not the best general solution. (eg, hardcoding the text ".net" is a terrible approach, but for a quick hack this is fine.)

Comment: Or to void duplicating then negating the condition: `FNR==NR{ip[$1]=$2;next} {print $1, ip[$1]}`. @user3834663 this is absolutely basic awk - read the first couple of chapters of Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to understand this script and then finish reading it before attempting any more shell programming.

Comment: In the similar manner, if the input1.txt has only the short name like below. How should I match ?  abcd
bcad
cagh
degh
usna

Comment: @user3834663  I do not understand your question.  Are you asking about the case in which input1.txt is all on one line?

Comment: input1.txt has short names with out ".net" and I need to get the same result in the output.txt by comparing the input2.txt

Comment: You edited the question so that my answer no longer works!  Don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

alternatives to `awk`

```
join <(sort input1) <(sort input2)

abcd.net 169.254.0.2
bcad.net 169.254.0.3
cagh.net 169.254.0.4
degh.net 169.254.0.5
usna.net 169.254.0.6
```

or good old grep

```
grep -f input1 input2

abcd.net 169.254.0.2
bcad.net 169.254.0.3
cagh.net 169.254.0.4
degh.net 169.254.0.5
usna.net 169.254.0.6
```